# html element background makes link un-clickable

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, overlap, clickable

I have three link `<a>` elements with a background but half the link isn't clickable because the background overlaps the text. Does anyone know a solution?

Here is an example of what i've done

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    li     
    {   list-style-type:none;
        list-style:none;
        position:relative;
        height:100px;
    }
#middle
{   width:350px;
    background:url("images/middle.png");
    left:405px;
    height:250px;
    padding-top:50px;
    background-size:100%;
}
#left
{   left:275px;
    width:240px;
    height:150px;
    padding:150px 60px 0 0;
    background:url("images/left.png");
    background-size:100%;
}
#right
{   left:580px;
    width:235px;
    height:150px;
    padding:150px 0 0 70px;
    background:url("images/right.png");
    background-size:100%;
}
   #test
    {   height:325px;
    }
    .Item
    {   position:absolute;
    font-size:33px;
    float:left;
    margin:15px;
    font-family: Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    text-align:center;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="test">
    <li id="left" class="Item"><a href="#">I want to<br>have some<br>text here</strong></a></li>
    <li id="middle" class="Item"><a href="#">I want to<br>have some<br>text here</strong></a></li>
    <li id="right" class="Item"><a href="#">I want to<br>have some<br>text here</strong></a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The HTML seems to be broken. You have several closing `</strong>` tags, but no opening `<strong>` tags to match them.

Comment: @Boaz is right, run it through http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input ; correcting those errors will help in the long run.

Comment: Why are you using breaks. It would make more sense to limit the size of your a href, adding z-index wont solve this, you have some major coding issue as Boaz has said.

Comment: The reason i've used breaks is because the picture background is a chunk of a circle (like a pie graph) so I need the lines to be long at the top and short at the bottom. I tried to post the actual site but it changed it into code...I have a hosted example of what i'm doing here www.jpginc.com.au/temp.html

Answer (score 1):

Add a Z-Index like that :

```
#middle
{   width: 350px;
    background: url("images/middle.png");
    left: 405px;
    height: 250px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    background-size: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: I've played around with the z-index's but the problem is that no matter which item i bring to the front it will overlap the other items. here is what I'm trying to do www.jpginc.com.au/temp.html As you can see some of the text will be overlapped no matter what z-indexing i use...unless i'm missing something?

Comment: As per the definition of z-index - `The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.`, I set my z-index value to be a large negative integer and my links became clickable with the background!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could merge the three pictures into one as shown in the page.Then start your layout using the new merged picture as background-image.When I want to build my website,I always draw a sketch of my website.I will treat the test div as a whole and set a background-image attribute for it.Feel sorry for my pool expression.Hope to solve your question.

Comment: That would work except I have a javascript function that moves the pictures towards the mouse cursor when it gets close so I need separate pictures. What I really need is to make only the text clickable, not the background. Is that possible?